# Pre-define a check list in Trello

Tags: trello, trello-lists

In Trello, can you pre-define a check list automatically?

We could use this to check off Product order and provision stages.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a card with the list you want, and then use this card as a template, by copying the card to the list you want.
For things like this, I actually have a list with is just templates of cards I use whenever I need.

Answer (score 1):

Trello just recently (last week) implemented the [Checklist Copy](https://trello.com/c/GOHBlxgB) feature: when you add a new checklist, you can now *"Copy Items From…"* an existing card's checklist.